# Notational convention $\frac{0}{0}=0$ in series context.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

Let $H=(H,(\cdot, \cdot))$ be a Hilbert space and $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset H$ a complete orthonormal set in $H$. Given $u \in H$, in some papers, for instance $[1, \text{Theorem 4.10}]$ and $[3, \text{page 257}]$, the authors consider a series of the form
$$
\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus J}\frac{1}{a_n}(u, v_n)v_n \cdot a_n \tag{1}
$$
where $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $J:=\{i \in \mathbb{N} \; ; \; a_i=0\}$ is a finite set. Obviously, by $(1)$ we have
$$
\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus J}\frac{1}{a_n}(u, v_n)v_n \cdot a_n=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus J}(u, v_n)v_n.
$$

On the other hand, it is well know (see $[2$, Theorem $9.12$ $]$) that we can write
$$
u=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(u, v_n)v_n = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus J}(u, v_n)v_n+\sum_{n \in J}(u, v_n)v_n. \tag{2}
$$

Making a notational convention, namely
$$
0=\frac{0}{0} \tag{3}
$$
the authors write then by $(1)$ and $(2)$ the following
$$
\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus J}\frac{1}{a_n}(u, v_n)v_n \cdot a_n =\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{a_n}(u, v_n)v_n \cdot a_n = u.
$$

**Question.** In this context, why the notational convention in $(3)$ can be considered?

In the book $[4, \text{Section $8.5$}]$ the division by zero is discussed, but I haven't been able to conclude whether or not I can even consider $(3)$. Any suggestion?

$[1]$ Albert, John P. *Positivity Properties and Stability of Solitary–Wave Solutions of Model Equations For Long Waves*. Communications in partial differential equations $17.1-2 (1992): 1-22.$

$[2]$ Bachman G. and Narici, L., Functional Analysis. New York: Academic Press, $2000$.

$[3]$ Freeden, Willi, and M. Zuhair Nashed. *Ill-posed problems: operator methodologies of resolution and regularization*. Handbook of Mathematical Geodesy. Birkhäuser, Cham, $2018. 201-314.$

$[4]$ Suppes, P., *Introduction to logic*. D. Van Nostrand Co., Inc., New York, $1957$.

Comment: I (probably naively) don't think it's worth dwelling on too much. It's a way to compactify the notation. Just as how $0^0$ is undefined, but we write

$$p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$$

for polynomials, and still have them defined at $x=0$ by letting $0^0=1$. The alternative would be to write

$$p(x) = a_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n a_i x^i$$

In this case we avoid having to get rid of $J$ each and every time to keep the expression well-defined. I don't know if there might be a deeper reason for this convention in this instance however. (Or if you want said deeper explanation and I'm overlooking it)

Comment: Except there is no real algebraic reason for $0^0$ to be undefined, while there is obvious reasons to treat $\frac00$ as undefined. But you are essentially correct, it's just notation, intended as a shorthand. As long as you know what it "really" means, and only use it in this context... @PrincessEev

Comment: @PrincessEev None of the above comments gave a satisfactory explanation, unfortunately. I would like a deeper and more mathematically coherent explanation. Since, we cannot to obtain the expression for $u$ if we don't able do sum over whole $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 2):

There is no serious mathematical content behind that convention... and certainly no assertion that $0/0=0$ in any numerical sense. Rather, to say this is a (rather cavalier) version of saying that, if $a_n=0$, then just drop that term entirely in the renormalized infinite sum.

The only small mathematical point is that the *formula* for properly renormalizing the coefficients is not correct for $a_n=0$... For other reasons, we know that in that case the $n$th renormalized coefficient should still be $0$...

I myself would indeed be disquieted by saying that a thing is true "by convention", as opposed to giving a good reason. In that regard, the author somewhat misrepresented the situation, but there's nothing serious hiding behind that glibness.

Comment: So, is mathematically coherent to say that $0=\frac{0}{0}$?

Comment: @Guilherme, not really. But, more to the point, we should not be finding ourselves in any situation where we actually have to do something with $0/0$. In the case at hand, the otherwise-correct formula for renormalization is not literally correct when $a_n=0$... and this "convention" does yield the correct renormalized coefficient... but we knew its correctness for other (simple!) reasons, not because of such craziness.

Comment: What you means by ''renormalization'' ?

Comment: By "renormalization", I mean your second displayed (not-numbered) line. You multiplied-and-divided by $a_n$... which is dangerous if $a_n=0$, ... but the term would have been $0$ already if $a_n=0$, so, while the formulaic business that is correct for $a_n\not=0$ fails for $a_n=0$, it really doesn't matter, because those summands were $0$ from the outset...

Comment: Why the term would have been $0$ if $a_n=0$? That is, why $\frac{1}{a_n}(u, v_n)v_n \cdot a_n=0$ for each $n \in J$? As I understand it, that's what you mean..

Comment: Well, I think that the manipulation/computation _prior_ to what you show and discuss would have had some disclaimer about $a_n=0$... The details depend on what context you want to discuss this in, but the point is that, unless you're trying to prank someone (possibly yourself) or they're trying to prank you, there should not be any need to "make sense of $0/0$".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138406/discussion-between-guilherme-and-paul-garrett).

Comment: Or just send me email, if you'd like, ... Easier for me to compose things there.